# Null Pointer when getting object from h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, converters, selectonemenu

I am trying to get Object "Plage" from h:selectOneMenu ,That's why I created a Converter ,it convert String id to Plage object existing in database using dao (hibernate )
Here my xhtml code :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="pays" styleClass="form-control selectpicker" value="#{service.plage}"
           converter="Convert" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{moyen.plages_l}" var="pl" 
                itemValue="#{pl}" itemLabel="plage entre #{pl.min} et #{pl.max}" />

           </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here code of Converter :

```
@FacesConverter(value="Convert")
public class PlageConverter implements Converter {

@Autowired
PlageBo plageBo;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = Integer.valueOf(value);
    Plage pl = plageBo.getPlagebyid(id);
    return pl;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1,
        Object service) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Plage plage_conv = (Plage) service;
    String idAsString = String.valueOf(plage_conv.getId_plage());
    return idAsString;
}


public PlageBo getPlageBo() {
    return plageBo;
}

public void setPlagebo(PlageBo plageBo) {
    this.plageBo = plageBo;
}}
```

I overrite equals() and haschode() in Plage class :
public class Plage implements Serializable {

```
private int id_plage;
private Double min;
private Double max;
private MoyenPaiement_pays moyenPaiement_pays;
//Getters & Setters 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.equals(arg0);
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Plage that = (Plage) o;
        if ( id_plage!=that.id_plage)  return false;    
        if (max != null ? !max.equals(that.max) : that.max != null) return false;
        if (min != null ? !min.equals(that.min) : that.min != null) return false;
        if (!moyenPaiement_pays.equals(that.moyenPaiement_pays))  return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int result = max.hashCode();
            result = 31 * result + (min != null ? min.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
    }
```

When I try to get the variable plage in Bean 
I got this error :

```
1100: JSF1073 : javax.faces.FacesException intercepté durant le traitement de PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=null
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.handleGetObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Formatter.formatMessage(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When i change it it gave me : java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.Dialpass.model.Plage 
The itemValue should be an Object not an integer @VasilLukach

Comment: If your value in `h:selectOneMenu` is object (not id), that check code in your converter: `int id = Integer.valueOf(value);` it expect that value is id.

Comment: The probleme is where to link the Bo with the converter @VasilLukach